# Saving data from custom UITableViewCell Xib to another View Controller and saving to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

This has been a challenge for me for some reason. It may be the logic but I think I need to be using a protocol. I have a simple app that I am trying to save user inputted data to Firebase. I was able to do this without a tableview but once I added it I began to lose understanding.

App flow: Login> Homepage with tableview and + button > + take you to add screen to input into 4 UITextFields with xibs. > there I want to save the data from the inputted cells and save to fb. I know how to save to FB but I am having a hard time understanding how to get data from the UITextField/xib text into the right place. Thank you in advance!

```
struct RecipeData {
    
    let user: String
    let recipeName: String
    let ingredientsText: String
    let directionsText: String
    let servingsNumber: String
    let image: String?
    let id = UUID().uuidString
}
```

```
class RecipeNameCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var name: String?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textField.placeholder = "Recipe Name..."
        textField.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
}
```

```
class HomeScreenViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var logout: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var add: UIBarButtonItem!

    var data = [RecipeData]()
    
    var recipeNamed: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "RecipeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    @IBAction func logoutPress(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func addRecipePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "add", sender: self)
    }
    
}

extension HomeScreenViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeCell
        
        cell.recipeNameLabel.text = "Testing..."
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

```
class AddRecipeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmented: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var ingredientsView: UIView!
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var data = [RecipeData]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPressed))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
        
        
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "RecipeNameCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "recipeName")
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "ServingSizeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "servings")
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "PrepTimeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "prep")
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "CookTimeTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cook")
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        }
        
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        }
        
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        }
        
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func cancelPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       
        
    }
    
}

extension AddRecipeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //        let data = data[indexPath.row]
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeName", for: indexPath) as! RecipeNameCell
            
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "servings", for: indexPath) as! ServingSizeTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prep", for: indexPath) as! PrepTimeTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cook", for: indexPath) as! CookTimeTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
        
    }
    
    //    func sendToFirebase() {
    //
    //
    //            let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
    //            let newRecipeRef = db.collection("Recipe").document(id)
    //            newRecipeRef.setData([
    //                "Recipe Name" : recipeName,
    //                "User" : user!,
    //            ])
    //            { err in
    //                if let err = err {
    //                    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
    //                } else {
    //                    print("Document added with ID:\(newRecipeRef)")
    //                }
    //            }
    //        }
    
    
}
```

```
 
    func sendToFirebase() {
        
        
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
        let newRecipeRef = db.collection("Recipe").document(id)
        newRecipeRef.setData([
            "Recipe Name" : recipeName,
            "User" : user!,
        ])
        { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document added with ID:\(newRecipeRef)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITextFieldDelegate` to get data from cells.

In `RecipeNameCell` comment this line `textField.delegate = self`

Now in `AddRecipeViewController` update your `cellForRowAt`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //        let data = data[indexPath.row]
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeName", for: indexPath) as! RecipeNameCell
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "servings", for: indexPath) as! ServingSizeTableViewCell
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prep", for: indexPath) as! PrepTimeTableViewCell
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cook", for: indexPath) as! CookTimeTableViewCell
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Now Implement `func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)` in `AddRecipeViewController`

```
extension AddRecipeViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
     func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    switch textField.tag {

    case 0:
          let recipeName = textField.text!
          print(recipeName)
          objRecipe.recipeName = textField.text // same for all
    case 1:

        let servingSize = textField.text!
        print(servingSize)
    /// and so on....

    default: break
    }

    }

}
```

Now pass this data to your Firebase.

Update your model

```
struct RecipeData {

var user: String?
var recipeName: String?
var ingredientsText: String?
var directionsText: String?
var servingsNumber: String?
var image: String?
let id = UUID().uuidString
```

}

declare object in `var objRecipe = RecipeData.init()`  `AddRecipeViewController` and update `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you. Just so I dont confuse myself further, where do I implement saving to fb? I have the commented out func for it in AddRecipeViewController

Comment: if you want all data need to submit at once, then create one model and store data. after all, data-filled or your validation complete then pass that model to FB.

Comment: Thank you again! That does make sense on how to retrieve the info from the model. I am still a little confused now on how to impliment the write to the DB when the savePressed. I updated showing the Firebase func